# Error while loading JSP page

Tags: eclipse, struts2, tomcat7

I am doing a Web Project in java using Eclipse. Even After making changes in the code, when i run the program,the change is not reflected. I am pretty sure that the programming part is correct. Can someone please help me with this?.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure the code is correct ?? If so there are chances that your server is maintaining an instance of the previous compilation. try deleting your module work directory and cleaning your server. hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clean your server's work directory when this occurs. Also building the project explicitly will solve this issue.